# SSH connection from Raspberry Pi to windows not working

Tags: ssh, samba, rsync

I want to make Sync a folder in windows to raspberry pi, which is connected via ethernet cable. I could write a program in windows to perform this operation and it executes well. But I dont want to run any program in the windows machine to push data to raspberry pi, rather I would like to write a program in Pi, to pull data from windows. I know there are several tools for this task, like rsync, samba, cifs, etc. But all those tools are built on top of SSH I assume. I tried to work with all the mentioned tools, none of them works.

---

While trying to debug the whole thing, I came to know that Pi, is hanging while trying to connect to the windows machine via SSH. When I try this 'sudo ssh -vvv computername@ipaddress' this is the output

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "169.254.71.106" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 169.254.71.106 [169.254.71.106] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 169.254.71.106 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 169.254.71.106 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Even Telnet doesnt work. When I execute 'sudo telnet ipaddress 22', this is the output.

```
trying <ipaddress> ...
```

Just Ping works. So, whats the problem here with ssh in this case? I disabled firewalls and enabled network sharing in windows as well. I made sure ssh-client and ssh-server and installed and running on windows as well. Is there a way to sync windows folder with raspberry pi, without using ssh?

Comment: Newer versions of Rasbian have SSH disabled by default.  Can you SSH from windows to your Pi?

Comment: I enabled SSH in Rasbian. And i could SSH from windows to Pi, using Putty.

Comment: I am just using ethernet cable to connect System with Pi. No router is involved.

Comment: Are you running an SSH server on your Windows machine? OpenSSH for example?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I started SSH server on windows, and now its asking password, when I run ssh in Pi. Whats the password its expecting?

Comment: Your Windows login

Comment: I dont have a windows login password

Comment: Then it will depend on the SSH server you set up and its own configuration.

Comment: your question has nothing to do with RPi .... it is a microsoft windows question .... you will have better luck researching a solution on sites that deal with windows

Comment: Answer lied in configuring windows accordingly, its not a windows question though. But anyway, another aspect of my question is, how to sync windows folder with raspberry pi, without running anything in windows (including ssh server)

Comment: from the comments it appears that you ran an SSH server on the windows machine .... is that the solution that you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Windows doesn't automatically host an SSH or Telnet server.  You will have to set one up on the Windows machine.